# ERROR: recursive reference in a subquery

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

I have a table 'visits' containing names of 'train', 'country' and 'city'.

Country and city are the country and stations to which train visits.
Country names are unique however city names can be same.

I want to find out minimum trains for given country names, so as to visit all the stations in those country.

My Approach:

First I will select a train which visits most of the stations of given country/countries, then i need to select a train which visits most of the stations from unvisited stations of given country/countries.

I am trying following CTE but couldn't get rid of error: 'recursive reference in a subquery'.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
selectedTrains(name) AS(
    select train
    from visits
    where country in (select country from countries)
    group by train
    order by count(city) DESC
    LIMIT 1

    UNION

    select train
    from visits
    where country in (select country from countries)
      and city not in (
              select city
              from visits
              where train in (select name from selectedTrains)
                and country in (select country from countries)
             )
    group by train
    order by count(city) DESC
    LIMIT 1
),
countries(country) AS (
    select country_name
    from country_data
    where country_name in ("USA","China","India")
)
SELECT * FROM train_data WHERE train_no IN selectedTrains;
```

Comment: Rewrite the query so that `selectedTrains` does not appear in a subquery. And you cannot use ORDER BY/LIMIT in a compound query; they apply only to the result.

Comment: That is what i am asking.. how can I rewrite query such that selectedTrains does not appear in a subquery?

Comment: Use a join, and/or "FROM (subquery)". But the [basic algorithm](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte) does not look at previous rows more than once, so you cannot check unvisited stations this way; you would have to carry the cities as an additional column through the recursion. And I doubt that your approach is guaranteed to result in the optimal solution; is this required?

Comment: I am still stuck in this.
I did it outside sql but it is taking more time.
Can you provide a solution?

Comment: You did not answer my last question. And while a CTE might be possible, this algorithm should better be implemented in an imperative programming language.

Comment: Yes, this is required. we can change the approach but output should be correct.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "correct"? And why do you need to do this in SQLite?

Comment: Data is in sqlite database where visits table contains more than 18 million records. Frequent connections to sqlite from python is taking time, so i want to do all the processing in sql. I haven't tried loading all data in numpy array as it may require huge memory.

Comment: I used "correct" for required output. i.e. output should contain minimum number of trains that will pass through all the stations.

Comment: As I said, I don't think this algorithm guarantees the correct output. And SQLite will have to load all the data anyway, and the temporary state needed for the CTE might be larger than your own data structure.

Comment: Can you suggest an algorithm which result in the optimal solution?